# Simple BFS algorithm in java between two object of coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

i'm a beginner in java and am having a lot of trouble implementing the BFS algorithm.

I need to make the body of this method:

```
List<Coordinate> getShortestPath(Coordinate start,
                                 Coordinate end)
```

The Coordinate object takes in an int row and int column. it also has the `getCol()` and `getRow()` methods implemented in it already.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done up to now?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and explain where **exactly** you are stuck.